# What does "He climbed the mountain" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction

Does it have the same meaning as "He climbed up the mountain."

Comment: Since mountains are high, _up_ is implied. One can't climb a mountain without moving upwards. Just as when you fall from a mountain, it's assumed that you fall _down_. However, it can be mentioned, even if it is redundant. The more interesting thing about _climb the mountain_ is that it combines an durative action (climbing on a mountain) with a punctual event (reaching the top); this is called an "achievement" predicate.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you always.  But do these sentences have the same meaning?  I thought they did.  But Peter Shor said "The reason y0u can say "I took the elevator up" but not "I climbed the mountain up" is that the mountain doesn't actually go up, but the elevator does."  So I thought maybe the two sentences have different meanings.  Beside that, I want to know why the mountain has to be able to move up in order to use "Up" in that sentence.  Adverbs describe verbs and "Up" is an adverb.  It describes the verb "Climb," not "The mountain."  I want to know what he tried to explain to me.

Comment: @AS - Pay attention to where *up* is placed in the sentence.  “climb up the mountain” vs “took the elevator up”.

Comment: @Jim In my previous question, my question was why "He climbed the mountain up" is correct and the above answer is one of the answers I've received.  I don't know what you are trying to teach me.

Comment: The contexts are different - you move upwards inside an elevator (it moves up with you), but you climb upwards on the surface of a mountain while it stays still.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one climbs up the mountain.  Then one climbs down it.

In isolation, I would assume someone who "climbed Mount Example" had climbed to the top, and then back down it.  So, "He climbed [up] Mount Example and suffered a heart attack" has different meanings according to whether you put in the word:  without implies that he completed the round trip first, and with, that he was on the mountain, probably the summit, when he suffered it.

A context, however, could make them identical.  "He climbed [up] Mount Example and watched the sunset before taking a helicopter ride back home" means the same whether you put in the word or not.

Comment: Thank you, but this answer is hard for me to understand.  But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To a native speaker, if you “climb up” a mountain, at the end of your exertions, you are higher on the mountain than you were previously.

If you “climb” a mountain, you reach the top of that mountain.  You have successfully summited the peak.

Answer (score 0):

He **climbed** the mountain= He **climbed up** the mountain

*climb* (go up)- He climbed the mountain. *climb up* (go up)- He climbed up the mountain.

But we cannot say 'He climbed the mountain' to mean 'He **climbed down** the mountain'.

climb down= move down